# Can I beautify javascript with uglifyjs via API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs2

Can I programmaticaly beautify JavaScript code with UglifyJS library? When I try to use something like

```
var uglifyjs = require('uglify-js');

...

var options = { compress: false, mangle: false, beautify: true };
var code = uglifyjs(source, options);
```

I get an error

```
{ error:
   { [DefaultsError: `beautify` is not a supported option]
     message: '`beautify` is not a supported option',
     ...
```

I don't want to use extra libraries, because I already use uglifyjs for minifying javascript in my code, and command-line version of uglifyjs can do this with command

```
uglifyjs --beautify -o script.js script.min.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs here (https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#minify-options) it looks like that needs to be in the Output Options

```
var options = { 
  compress: false, 
  mangle: false, 
  output: {
    beautify: true 
  }
};
var code = uglifyjs(source, options);
```